# Swing: How to align a JButton

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jbutton

I have been trying to align a JButton and i have been search google for a few things but none seem to work.  All code that i have found do not move the JButtons.  I wanty to align the JButtons so that they look like a Calculators face. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class CalculatorUI extends JFrame
{
    //Variables.
    private JTextField text1;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;
    private JButton button4;
    private JButton button5;
    private JButton button6;
    private JButton button7;
    private JButton button8;
    private JButton button9;
    private JButton button0;
    private JPanel pane;

    public CalculatorUI()
    {
        super ("Calculator");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        text1 = new JTextField(20);
        text1.setEditable(false);
        add(text1);
        button1 = new JButton("1");
        button1.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        add(button1);
        button2 = new JButton("2");
        add(button2);
        button3 = new JButton("3");
        add(button3);
        button4 = new JButton("4");
        add(button4);
        button5 = new JButton("5");
        add(button5);
        button6 = new JButton("6");
        add(button6);
        button7 = new JButton("7");
        add(button7);
        button8 = new JButton("8");
        add(button8);
        button9 = new JButton("9");
        add(button9);
        button0 = new JButton("0");
        add(button0);



        theHandler handler = new theHandler();
        text1.addActionListener(handler);
        button1.addActionListener(handler);
        button2.addActionListener(handler);
        button3.addActionListener(handler);
        button4.addActionListener(handler);
        button5.addActionListener(handler);
        button6.addActionListener(handler);
        button7.addActionListener(handler);
        button8.addActionListener(handler);
        button9.addActionListener(handler);
        button0.addActionListener(handler);

    }
    private class theHandler implements ActionListener
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String string = "";


        if(event.getSource() == text1)
        {
            string = String.format("Field1: %s", event.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == button1)
        {
            string = String.format("Field2: %s", event.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == button2)
        {
            string = String.format("Field3: %s", event.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == button3)
        {
            string = String.format("Pasword Field: %s", event.getActionCommand());
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
    }
    }


}
```

Comment: Google for the Java Swing layout manager tutorials. Therein lies your answer. Edit: the first hit was a bulls eye.

Comment: oops, seems the OP's account got deleted too fast.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to find an appropriate layout, and FlowLayout probably isn't the way to go.

I had pretty good luck with GridBayLayout for this kind of thing.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

But I also ended up writing my own layout manager for one unique task I encountered.  Wasn't particularly hard.

And in fact, just plain ol' GridLayout would work if ALL you need are buttons in a grid.  Would be easier, too.

Answer (score 4):

Since Marvo is giving specific recommendations, I'm going to contradict him a little and tell you to avoid using GridBagLayout until you're more familiar with the simpler layout managers. For instance for a grid of JButtons, use a GridLayout. If you want other components around this, consider placing the GridLayout-using JPanel inside of another JPanel that uses a different layout, say a BorderLayout -- you can nest JPanels with simple layouts to achieve complex GUI's. Again the tutorial will show you the way.